# How to install Google API's json-simple jar to a maven project?

Tags: java, import, maven-2

I've just made a java project with maven:

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=\
myproject -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven- archetype-quickstart
```

Then need to import a 3rd party jar, path is ~/Downloads/json-simple-1.1.1.jar, I tried the following commands:

```
mvn -e install:install-file -Dfile=~/Downloads/json_simple-1.1.1.jar\
-DgroupiId=org.json.simple - DartifactId=json_simple -Dversion=1.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

but an error occoured:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR  
[INFO] Missing group, artifact, version, or packaging information
```

I'm using maven 2.2.1, java 1.6.0_35 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency is already in maven central repository. Just the following dependency to the pom of your project and you are done:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Works Fine :) Thanks (y)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install json_simple locally.  It is in Maven Central.  Go to http://search.maven.org and search.

```
groupid:     com.googlecode.json-simple
artifactid:  json-simple
version      1.1.1
```

It is better to satisfy a dependency from Central rather than relying on one you installed locally.  For a start, it will make it easier for other people to build your code.

As for the build problem, I suspect that you have made a mistake in the dependencies section of your project's "POM.xml" file.

Comment: thanks, do I need to edit the POM.xml manually to add the dependency?

Comment: Yes ... unless your IDE has a Maven plugin that allows to add dependencies via a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remember the exact syntax but you can di the following:

Add thus as a dependency in the pom file of the project you want to build

The build will fail as this jar is not part of the repo yet

But maven will also generate the command to install the jar in repo copy paste that, change the path the jar and execute.

This should solve the purpose.

But looks like this jar is already part of some repo.gGoogle it out might just need to add a new repo